# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.sqlite.Conn.createArrayOf error while calling createArrayOf method on sqlite

Tags: jdbc, sqlite, java

I have Java code which uses the sqlite jdbc driver 3.7.2.

I am trying to call method `conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", elements)`, but it fails saying:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.sqlite.Conn.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;

Can anybody suggest me what should I do to make this working?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely using a JDBC 3.0 version of the SQLite JDBC driver, and that driver does not implement this method (which was added in JDBC 4 / Java 6). Because no implementation is available, Java throws an `AbstractMethodError`.

As far as I can tell from a quick google, SQLite doesn't actually provide a SQL `ARRAY` implementation so even if this method were 'implemented', it would most likely just throw an `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` as there is no actual support.