# How to use Array or List<> in one PrepareStatement (sqlite)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I try a lot of time to solve this so thank you for any help. 
How to use array in preparestatement? I do it like in this example [How to use an arraylist as a prepared statement parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842211/how-to-use-an-arraylist-as-a-prepared-statement-parameter) but it return me error, my code:

```
        //initialize
        ResultSet rs2; 
        connection2 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector(); 
        PreparedStatement statement2=connection2.prepareStatement("SELECT surname FROM users where id IN (?)");

        //like in the example linked, but it did not work:   
        Array array = connection2.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[]{"1", "2"});
        statement2.setArray(1, array);
        rs2=statement2.executeQuery();

        //to keep data from resultset, it works fine
        List<String> rsDATA = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs2.next()){ 
            rsDATA.add(rs2.getString("surname")); 
        }   
        for(int i = 0; i < rsDATA.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(rsDATA.get(i));
        }
        connection.close();
```

but it return error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
at lines: 

1)Array array = connection2.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[]{"1", "2"});
2(executeQuery();
```

It is very important for me to solve this. Thank you a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `IN` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT surname FROM users WHERE id IN (?)
```

and a `java.sql.Array` object as shown in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: I do it like you hint me, but as you can see it still return error, how it can be change? What I can do with it?

Comment: @arkani your sqlite JDBC driver is probably outdated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408591/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-sqlite-conn-createarrayof-error-while-calling. But as indicated in that answer, sqlite may not have a `java.sql.Array` implementation.

Comment: It true, sqlite not have  java.sql.Array implementation. So is there any another way to do it? It is a big project and I can't change jdbc..
Can statement can be done with some loop to skip array problem?